# Image Similarity Detection : What alternative to Graphlab Create

Tags: image, deep-learning, feature-detection, knn, graphlab

I've been using the fabulous Graphlab Create API for few month now.

Apple purchased Graphlab so I'm looking for an alternative capable of 
making a deep learning k-nearest neighbors model to find the most similar image to an input one.

With it is straightforward:

```
deep_train['deep_features'] = deep_learning_model.extract_features(...
knn_model = graphlab.nearest_neighbors.create(deep_train,feature
label='id')
knn_frame = knn_model.query(cat_test)
```

What library offer similar deep feature based knn approach in Python or any other language?